# PCB simulation of high speed ADC daughter card connected via FMC connector

Tags: pcb-design, adc, high-speed

A design using high speed ADC is to be carried out involving an FPGA as the master device. To simplify the prototype phase, a daughter board with the ADC shall be designed and connected to the FPGA development board via a HPC connector. This connector is design to be used with high speed links.

I want to have a starting point for investigation on how to complete the PCB design and simulation. I understand the basic theory behind high speed design which is impedance matching and PCB track length constraining. However, as far as I am aware, it also important to have a power supply network that is resistant to noise and is stable for the ADC. The question is, how to go about doing this in Zuken Cadstar or Altium Designer. Certainly, I will need information about the FPGA development board PCB to complete this type of simulation as well.

Any application note or book that can provide practical example of PCB design for a similar problem will go a great length and answering my questions.